# How to print enum description

Tags: java, enums

Im creating a Java application, I used enum to create movie category. When I input `MovieCategory.WAR` I would like to see `War movie(My description)` instead of `WAR`. How is it possible? I tried `MovieCategory.WAR.getDescription()` but does't work.

```
public enum MovieCategory {
   COMEDY("Comedy"), HORROR("Horror"), SCIFI("Sci-Fi"),
   ACTION("Action movie"), ROMANTIC("Romantic"),
   CLASSIC("Classic"), WAR("War movie");

   private final String description;

   MovieCategory(String description) {
       this.description = description;
   }

   public String getDescription() {
       return description;
   }
}
```

```
public class MovieManager {

    private List<Movie> movieList;

    public MovieManager() {
        this.movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        movieList.add(new Movie("Simple movie", MovieCategory.WAR,"Testing description.",167,12));
(...)
```

Comment: In enum your `War` is defined with only first letter upper case. But you try to get `WAR`

Comment: My mistake. It's WAR anyway and want to to print "War movie". It prints my enum's named WAR which I don't want to.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: @Cobra Can you check my Answer if it is what you are looking for?

Comment: I Edited my code, i will check the answer @geffchang thank you.

Comment: OK, I used toString method to return movie's description, but I don't know how to add new movie with description. It still displays WAR instead of War movie. Used toString method to return description. Used movieList.add but it still returns WAR to my ArrayList.

Comment: use `getDescription` not `toString`

Comment: @Cobra Could you check my 3rd update? I think JsonValue will fix your issue. Please Upvote and Accept if it's what you're looking for. :)

Comment: @geffchang I am so sorry for my late response. Thank you very much, brother! JsonValue annotation works perfectly. That's exactly what i was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enum works correctly:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Displays: Comedy
    System.out.println(COMEDY.getDescription());
    // Displays: COMEDY
    System.out.println(COMEDY);
  }
```

Or, maybe you want the `toString` method to use `description`?

```
public enum MovieCategory {
  COMEDY("Comedy");

  private final String description;

  MovieCategory(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return getDescription();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Displays: Comedy
    System.out.println(COMEDY.getDescription());
    // Displays: Comedy
    System.out.println(COMEDY);
  }
}
```

UPDATE #3: It seems the issue is the JSON response. If you want the description to be returned, you can annotate the `getDescription` method wtih `@JsonValue`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

public enum MovieCategory {
  WAR("War movie");

  private final String description;

  MovieCategory(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  @JsonValue
  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return getDescription();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Displays: Comedy
    System.out.println(WAR.getDescription());
    // Displays: Comedy
    System.out.println(WAR);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, brother! JsonValue annotation works perfectly. That's exactly what i was looking for, thank you!